# Angular 2: combine *ngIf and #template together

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

```
<p (mouseover)="info.innerText = 'Detailed info'" 
   (mouseout)="info.innerText = 'Mouseover for details'">
    Select it
</p>
<br>    
<p #info *ngIf="queuedTasks > 0">
    Mouseover for details
</p>
```

When i try to combine it, browser debugger says

> Error: self.context.info is undefined

Is it possible to use it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you read the whole angular 2 doc because I've never heard about #variable but #reference or #template ? So don't hesitate to check this link https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-template-reference-variable-example

References in Angular 2 must be declared using Viewchild decorator
In your case :

```
@ViewChild("info") info: any;
ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.info); // instead of self.context.info
   // this will give you the ElementRef value for your p element
}
```

If you need to display content inside a ngIf condition use `<p>{{info}}</p>` instead of `<p #info>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can find a solution for this, because `#info` doesn't exists when that `*ngIf` is `false`. But you can use a simple variable:

In your TS file:

```
export class MyComponent {
    public text = 'Mouseover for details';
    // ...
}
```

In your HTMl file:

```
<p (mouseover)="text = 'Detailed info'" 
   (mouseout)="text  = 'Mouseover for details'">
    Select it
</p>
<br>    
<p *ngIf="queuedTasks > 0">
    {{text }}
</p>
```

Or you can try `[hidden]` too instead of `*ngIf`.